# Yii1 function using

Tags: yii

I have a question about the Yii function
I have two functions

```
public function actionfuntion1
public function actionfuntion2
```

However someone has access to data from actionfuntion1 into actionfuntion2 
I have used

```
if (strii (yii :: app () -> request-> requestUri, 'actionfuntion2') == false) {die;
```

To stop him, is there any other

Comment: you can use `Yii::app()->controller->action->id instead` of `yii :: app () -> request-> requestUri`

Comment: i use requestUri to get other action, deny all action not true, how to only url of only function can be run, others can not add prefixes behind function to run other functions